# Furyblade Vampire vs Blinding Mage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The [Blinding Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlinding%20Mage%5d) has an ability to tap a target creature. [Furyblade Vampire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFuryblade%20Vampire%5d) has the ability to discard a card at the beginning of combat for +3/+0. I don't see who has to act first? Furyblade doesn't want to discard a card if it cannot attack, but the Blinding Mage might not want to spend the resources to tap if Furyblade isn't buffed? Who has the last say?

player1: discard card to buff Furyblade

(does player2 get the option to use abilities?)

player2: use Blinding Mage's ability to tap Furyblade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Furyblade Vampire has a triggered ability, and Blinding Mage has an activated ability. In this case, that means that the player with the Vampire has more restricted options, and basically has the worst expected outcomes with this interaction.

Here's how it plays out (let's say Amy controls the Furyblade Vampire, and Nat controls the Blinding Mage):

1. Amy's Beginning of Combat step starts. Furyblade Vampire's ability triggers and goes on the stack.
2. Both players have an opportunity to act. Nat can activate Blinding Mage's ability at this time, but he's probably better off waiting.
3. Furyblade Vampire's ability resolves. At this point, Amy chooses whether to discard a card.
4. Both players have another opportunity to act. At this point, Nat can choose whether to activate Blinding Mage, depending on whether Amy chose to discard a card.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of events (and steps) is as follows:

1. Game moves to Beginning of Combat step.
2. Furyblade trigger goes on stack.
3. Both players gain priority (Active, then non-active)
4. Trigger resolves, controller may discard to buff.
5. Both players gain priority (Active, then non-active)
6. Game moves to Declare Attackers step.

At either steps 3 or 5 Blinding Mage can be activated.  Since both times are before Declare Attackers, if Furyblade is tapped it can't attack. Since step 5 is after the buff has been applied, tapping it there wastes the buff.

Answer (score 2):

The Blinding Mage will have the opportunity to tap the Furyblade Vampire after its controller has decided if they will discard a card or not.

In Magic who gets/has to act is based on a system called priority. The super short version of priority is a player needs to have priority in order to cast spells or activate abilities. Before any spell or ability resolves all players must pass priority without doing anything. If priority is passed by all players without anything being on the stack the game moves to the next step or phase.

The Combat Phase has several steps inside of it, the first two the Beginning of Combat Step and Declare Attackers Step are the ones that are relevant to this question.

The Vampire's ability triggers *'At the beginning of combat on your turn'*, this means that it triggers during the Beginning of Combat Step. After the ability resolves (and you have chosen either to discard a card or not) your opponent will receive priority (they technically also get priority before the ability resolves, but since they wouldn't want to use their Mage's ability then I'm skipping over it), which means they have the opportunity to cast spells or activate abilities like Blinding Mage's.

The Declare Attackers Step is when you would actually declare the Vampire as an attacker if it is not tapped. Note that you can't just try and do something like 'I discard a card to the Furyblade's trigger and attack with it.' to try and skip your opponents ability to tap it. If you try and do something like this they have every right to back the game up and tap your Vampire.